# ansible 2.6.2: playbook works when executed with ansible-playbook command but not in AWX 1.0.7.2

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, authorized-keys

I've seen many posts claiming that playbooks work properly when executed with ansible CLI but not in AWX. However, I didn't find any solution to my issue. To make it simple, I have the following role:

```
---
- name: Append Public key in authorized_keys file
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ username }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

It is called as follows:

```
- name: copy root public key to nodes
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  hosts: jenkins-nodes
  roles:
    - role: copy-keys
      username: root
```

Running it with the CLI, as shown below:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini -u root <my-playbook> ---vvv
```

works as expected and displays the following:

```
TASK [copy-keys : Append Public key in authorized_keys file 
***************************************************************
task path: /opt/jenkins-cluster/roles/copy-keys/tasks/main.yml:2
...
ok: [jenkins-agent-1] => {
"changed": false,
"comment": null,
"exclusive": false,
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "comment": null,
        "exclusive": false,
        "key": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCuF9U2HvzUubuYYZxJaEu/1nls7RLAZO+qcJF37RIepTSLOgoPsluq7uVRhEnadqnB0yVWccZYHs6WEp5Fo2QIRDRho4+TuACB26EE4GTYGnozyMwOwVcTzRo0CiUXfo3IZKWwQ+v8WwBMae3EpYrbrEZy6lLS8K85uYseyjg1myRhEsltdSiNnHun7p09/v/HMq2KsZcmx6nTg66QvkbbnFvv9UpGQ1J6gvimp11r5r1hwXaB7ejTwrxMICvaE2Flq3WGeaB35I4dYFsrWNK1CalP7jPF+MRgqHUrjoOy5hxp3zSXunfGWeRJCaJY5hYDLp3hTGrt8BwcdD+8Gy7r root@inf-inone01-prd",
        "key_options": null,
        "keyfile": "/root/.ssh/authorized_keys",
        "manage_dir": true,
        "path": null,
        "state": "present",
        "unique": false,
        "user": "root",
        "validate_certs": true
    }
},
"key": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCuF9U2HvzUubuYYZxJaEu/1nls7RLAZO+qcJF37RIepTSLOgoPsluq7uVRhEnadqnB0yVWccZYHs6WEp5Fo2QIRDRho4+TuACB26EE4GTYGnozyMwOwVcTzRo0CiUXfo3IZKWwQ+v8WwBMae3EpYrbrEZy6lLS8K85uYseyjg1myRhEsltdSiNnHun7p09/v/HMq2KsZcmx6nTg66QvkbbnFvv9UpGQ1J6gvimp11r5r1hwXaB7ejTwrxMICvaE2Flq3WGeaB35I4dYFsrWNK1CalP7jPF+MRgqHUrjoOy5hxp3zSXunfGWeRJCaJY5hYDLp3hTGrt8BwcdD+8Gy7r root@inf-inone01-prd",
"key_options": null,
"keyfile": "/root/.ssh/authorized_keys",
"manage_dir": true,
"path": null,
"state": "present",
"unique": false,
"user": "root",
"validate_certs": true
}
...
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
```

When I execute exactly the same thing in AWX I get:

```
TASK [copy-keys : Append Public key in authorized_keys file] 
*******************
task path: /var/lib/awx/projects/_39__jenkins_cluster/roles/copy-keys/tasks/main.yml:2
 [WARNING]: Unable to find '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to
see paths)
 [WARNING]: Unable to find '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to
see paths)
fatal: [jenkins-agent-1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a 
<class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}
```

The exception is saying that the file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, here /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub for th user root, cannot be located as it doesn't exist. My understanding is that the authorized_key module will add to the authorized_keys file on the target host the content of the /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file on the ansible controller. And this file exists:

```
PROD root@inf-inone01-prd jenkins-cluster $ cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa 
 AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCuF9U2HvzUubuYYZxJaEu/1nls7RLAZO
+qcJF37RIepTSLOgoPsluq7uVRhEnadqnB0yVWccZY
Hs6WEp5Fo2QIRDRho4+TuACB26EE4GTYGnozyMwOwVcTzRo0CiUXfo3IZKWwQ
+v8WwBMae3EpYrbrEZy6lLS8K85uYseyjg1myRhEsltd 
SiNnHun7p09/v/HMq2KsZcmx6nTg66QvkbbnFvv9UpGQ1J6gvimp11r5r1hwXaB7ejTwrxMIC
vaE2Flq3WGeaB35I4dYFsrWNK1CalP7jPF+MRgqHUrjoOy5hxp3zSXunfGWeRJCaJY5hYDLp3hTGrt8BwcdD+8Gy7r 
root@inf-inone01-prd
PROD root@inf-inone01-prd jenkins-cluster $
```

Obviously the authorized_keys module is not able to resolve ~/.ssh but how come it does it when ran with the CLI ?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated as, after having spent time to test the whole stuff such that to cover all the cases using the CLI, I thought that putting everything in AWX would be a matter of minutes. Which is unfortunatelly not.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Comment: Is AWX installed on same host where CLI is installed ? What host are you hitting ?

Comment: `~` is a `bash` thing.  The AWX does not run in an interactive shell, so `~` is not dereferenced.  Use the full path.

Comment: @Jack: makes sense but how come it works when ran with CLI ?

Comment: Because when running on the command line, you are in an interactive `bash` shell, which dereferences `~` for you.

Comment: @Jack: understood but I would expect that something like that: shell: ssh-keygen -b 2048 -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -q -N "" works but it doesn't neither. In colclusion: ansible scripts need heavy modifications and adaptations in order to be integrated in AWX. This as opposed to the AWX documentation which states that the process is very trivial.

Comment: I cannot speak for AWX, but I have been working with Ansible Tower (Ansible is my speciality as a Red Hat Consultant), and I have never had a playbook that works from `ansible-playbook` that I had to modify to work in Ansible Tower.

Comment: @Jack: as far as I know, AWX is the community edition of Ansible Tower, so I presume that's more or less the same thing. And yes, that's interesting to know that you've constantly needed to port your scripts from ansble CLI to Tower/AWX. This is not expected. Thanks anyway for the information.

Comment: @Nicolas You misunderstood.  I never had to change a playbook to make it work in Ansible Tower.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and the best solution I found involved using a custom credential type.

Examples how to set up custom credential types are explained very nicely [here](https://termlen0.github.io/2019/06/08/observations/) and [here](https://jpmens.net/2019/04/16/custom-credentials-in-ansible-tower-awx/).

In my case, I created a custom credential type called "SSH Keypair Credential" as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbuvI.png).

The input configuration:

```
fields:
  - id: my_ssh_private_key
    type: string
    label: ssh_private_key
    secret: true
    multiline: true
  - id: my_ssh_public_key
    type: string
    label: ssh_public_key
    secret: true
```

The injected configuration:

```
extra_vars:
  ssh_private_key: '{{ tower.filename.my_ssh_private_key }}'
  ssh_public_key: '{{ tower.filename.my_ssh_public_key }}'
file:
  template.my_ssh_private_key: '{{ my_ssh_private_key  }}'
  template.my_ssh_public_key: '{{ my_ssh_public_key  }}'
```

After creating the custom credential type, create the custom credential as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPmrq.png).

Then add the custom credential to the respective template to be used as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og70h.png).

The following playbook variables were used:

```
admin_username: "admin"
admin_public_sshkey: "{{ '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' | expanduser }}"
admin_private_sshkey: "{{ '~/.ssh/id_rsa' | expanduser }}"

admin_ssh_private_key: "{{ ssh_private_key | d(admin_private_sshkey) }}"
admin_ssh_public_key: "{{ ssh_public_key | d(admin_public_sshkey) }}"
```

The playbook when setting the authorized_key:

```
- name: Add admin user SSH authorized keys
  when: admin_ssh_public_key is defined
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ admin_username }}"
    key: "{{ lookup('file', admin_ssh_public_key) }}"
```